# Scroll to an element position not working on IOS

Tags: javascript

I have a button used to scroll down to the next `div` below the current container.
This works on all browsers on my computer but on an ipad (9.3.5) it scrolls to the top.

How can I make this more compatible?

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <button class="scroll">Scroll</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var scrollBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll');
for(i=0; i < scrollBtns.length; i++) {
  scrollDown(i);
};
function scrollDown(i) {
  scrollBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    var parent = scrollBtns[i].closest('#content > div');
    var winScroll = Math.max(window.pageYOffset, document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);
    var scrollPos = parent.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + winScroll;

    window.scrollTo({ top: scrollPos, behavior: 'smooth' });
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried `element.scrollIntoView()`? Just an idea..

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ `scrollIntoView()` is even less compatible isn't it?

Comment: Support for it doesn't [look](https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview) that bad now

Comment: If element.scrollIntoView() isn't available just use window.scrollTo({ top: scrollPos, behavior: 'smooth' }); as a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

I originally thought it was an incorrect scroll position, but it looks like `scrollTo()` is the problem here. So to fix, I found the polyfill [Smooth Scroll](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) which seems to do the trick.